# What is the fastest way to upload files (i.e. least CPU cycles / file)?

Tags: cloud

What is the fastest way to upload files (i.e. least CPU cycles / file)? Say I have 1 million files on disk and I want to upload all of them to an HTTPS API with unlimited capacity. I want to fully saturate a fast cloud container network.

Code is running in a Docker container with 2-8 CPUs and 3 GB+ ram.

Node.js streams is pretty good but is CPU-bound w/ SSDs.

The root problem seems to that uploading a file means copying a file out of the kernel to userland and then back to the kernel and then to networking — which is CPU/memory heavy.

Comment: You need to add some more clarity, what type of machine is this, and the file format? You might just be using the wrong tool for the job, I've seen some pretty cool wasm/c code from graphics community and they swap out code like this all the time

Comment: Added description of environment. File format doesn't matter as to us it's just bytes we're uploading — we don't process the file on either the client or server.